# Change logger class of external packages

Tags: python, logging

I want to use my own logger class to for all logger instances, the goal is to have consistent text formatting and easily save all records in the same file.

But I'm using a library that create a logger instance when I import it, then log messages when I run my code.

The solution seems to use [setLoggerClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass) but it have to be called before the import stage. Which gives me:

```py
import logging
from utils.logger import MyLogger

logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)

import other.packages

# Remove the handlers set on the external logger and replace by mine.
for handler in external_logger.handlers[:]:
    external_logger.removeHandler(handler)
external_logger.setup_my_handlers()

# Some code
```

This is working but looks dirty and doesn't satisfy [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code style guide line. I'm also afraid to break it after any refractory.

Is there any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your package structure is but this is code that should be placed in the `__init__.py` file for a package that gets imported before all other packages that uses logging gets imported. If your package structure had a high level package, e.g. *my_application*, from which all other packages were descended (this would be the ideal situation), as in the following diagram ...

```
my_application
   __init_.py
   package_1
       __init__.py
       package_1_1
           __init__.py
   package_2
       __init__.py
   etc.
```

... then you would want to put the *log initialization code* in file *my_application/__init__.py* because this package initialization code will always be executed when *any* of the above packages is imported. If there is no such *parent* package, then perhaps there is a package that just happens to be already get imported before all other packages that use logging. Finally, you can always create a new package with just an `__init__.py` file into which you place your code and then modify your scripts to import that new package as the first imported package.

Comment: I don't have such structure in my project yet, so I guess that I would be in the last case. Then what would be the difference between creating a package with just an `__init__.py` file and importing a file that contains the `setLoggerClass` statement?

Answer (score 1):

This code below may solve this problem:

> logging.getLogger(external_logger_name).propagate = False

In logging module, it has multi loggers, it is a tree structure, and all other logger is child of "root" logger. When you using:

> logging.info('message')

Actually logging module will find all logger which is enabled to logging,  You can set one logger's propagate attribute False to disable it.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: According to the documentation `propagate` attribute is to deal with events propagation. I don't see how it answer the question. Can you explain your idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called structlog that handles this case pretty well. [On this page](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#rendering-using-logging-based-formatters)
they show you how to setup a formatter and set that on the root logger. (You will need to setup logging before any other python package tries to setup logging, 99% of the time this means at the top of your entrypoint file). This method shows how you can now use stdlib and structlog loggers side-by-side while having consistent output (in your case some nice formatting)

Comment: I didn't know this library, I will take a look. But if I need to run a script to set it up, then I will probably fall in the same problem, no?

Comment: I should have phrased it differently "running a script" is not what I meant. The point is that in python you need to setup logging. If it is already done and you write code that does this setup, then your function is not getting this clean slate. The root logger might already have all kinds of handlers attached to it. So I meant to say: "you will need to run logging setup as early as possible, before 3rd party libraries try to setup logging", some do this in an invasive way

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem here is library that youre using creating a different logger instance 'when you import' it. Instead write a function in that library that creates a logger instance only when you use it. Then write your code as

```
import logging
import other.packages
from utils.logger import MyLogger
logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
...function thet creates logger instance...

#more code
```

Comment: `setLoggerClass` doesn't work if the logger instance is already created. And it is created during `import other.packages`. And I don't have control over the library code, I can't change the logger instance initialization.

Comment: You dont like the way it looks because your code is out of pep8 standards and looks dirty, but real problem is not on your code at the library that you imported. It should create logger instance if you want to use and when you use, not when you import it. Only way i can think of is if theres a method at this library that deletes logger instance so you can create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function that you can call multiple loggers in the same runtime which can save multiple log files. edit code with your parameters,

```
import os
import logging

if not os.path.exists(r"logs"):
 os.mkdir(r"logs")

def loggerInstance(logger_name, level=logging.DEBUG):
 logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
 logger.setLevel(level)
 format_string = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
 log_format = logging.Formatter(format_string, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
 # Creating and adding the console handler
 console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
 console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
 logger.addHandler(console_handler)
 # Creating and adding the file handler
 file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logger_name, mode='a')
 file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
 logger.addHandler(file_handler)
 return logger

CRLogger = loggerInstance(f"logs/" + "Log1.log")
CRLogger.info('Log File is Created Successfully')
```

This should work. if you are running in multiple loop or sessions or runtime, this will create a log each time even if it is runtime under the loop. you should save the log file name differently every time in order to that.

**NOTE:** if you want to save the log in the same file, keep the same name (xx.log) which will append every new runtime loggings.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you can change the behaviour of an existing logger, but not changing its class. Right?